# Exception Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, file, email, email-attachments, android-fileprovider

I am trying to setup FileProvider and i'm encountering a lot of problems. The latest is the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

My FileProvider looks like this:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.jernej.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>
```

My path xml file looks like this:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="csv_file" path="files/"/>
</paths>
```

And the in the MainActivitiy i use this code to pass the file to the intent

```
File exportDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "");
File file = new File(exportDir, "meritve.csv");
File pot=new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.jernej", pot);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/csv");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "mail.example@gmail.com");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send E-mail..."));
```

I have no idea if I even set up the FileProvider correctly. The file is in the directory /data/data/com.example.jernej.glukozko/files

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by putting my export file into another subfolder (exportFolder).

```
File exportDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "exportFolder"); // here is where i made the first fix
File file = new File(exportDir, "meritve.csv");
File pot=new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.example.jernej.fileprovider", pot); // this is the second fix

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/csv");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "mail.example@gmail.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send E-mail..."));
```

So I had to correct my path so now it looks like this:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <files-path name="csv_file" path="exportFolder/"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.jernej", pot);
```

use the `android:authorities` from manifest:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.jernej.fileprovider", pot);
```

**EDIT**

in your code: use

```
File exportDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "files"); //change here
File file = new File(exportDir, "meritve.csv");
```

Comment: I did that, but now another error comes up:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.jernej.glukozko/files/meritve.csv

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.jernej.glukozko/files/meritve.csv

Comment: try using: `<external-files-path name="csv_file"  path="files/" />`..instead of `<files-path name="csv_file" path="files/"/>`.

Comment: i have edited the answer...and do not need to change `<external-files-path name="csv_file" path="files/" />`...use your previous path: `<files-path name="csv_file" path="files/"/>`